# jQuery replacing span text not working

Tags: jquery, text, replace

I have a basic page where I am showing and hiding divs based off of button presses. As part of the page I want to change the headline to reflect the appropriate content.

Here is the HTML:

```
<h2 class="section_header left">
  <span>
     Missing <span id="category">People</span> Nationwide
  </span>
</h2>
```

Here is the jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('#allcat').click(function(){
     $('.child').show();
     $('.adult').show();
     $("#category").text("People");
   });
   $('#children').click(function(){
     $('.child').show();
     $('.adult').hide();
     $("#category").text("Children");
   });
   $('#adults').click(function(){
     $('.child').hide();
     $('.adult').show();
     $("#category").text("Adults");
   });
 });
```

I have tried .text() and .html()

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Can you create a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) please?

Comment: Works fine for me: http://jsfiddle.net/EB3gr/  What problems are you encountering?

Comment: just a guess, but does it work if you put quotes around document

Comment: Working fine for me : http://jsfiddle.net/RYh7U/120/.

Comment: That is sooo weird, it works for me too, but still not on my site. I'll continue debugging. I'm not getting any errors. Thanks guys.

Comment: may be your html generate auto Ids before your ID. could be like this `id="x:category"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I feel really dumb. This was a case of the same code twice in a page and overriding itself. The code above does work as expected when the developer gets his act together. Thanks for your help.

Comment: may be you were trying to make april fool :-)